# Encontrar o agrupar palabras que son parecidas

Tags: python

actualmente tengo una base de datos de ciudades, donde me gustaría realizar una limpieza para trabajar en un futuro con ella.

En esta base de datos, estoy intentando eliminar duplicados y dejar registros únicos, pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema, y es que tengo registros como estos:

- A Coruña
- A Coruna
- Acoruna
- Acoruña

¿Habría alguna manera de encontrar el patrón de estas palabras o alguna función o método para agrupar las palabras parecidas sintácticamente en Python?

En todas las he pasado a minúsculas y he eliminado signos de puntuación y demás, para que sea más fácil el análisis de estos duplicados.

Comment: Deberías proporcionar un juego de datos representativo de la entrada y también mostrar la salida que esperas. Pon también ciudades que se puedan confundir entre si.

Comment: Crea una funcion que compare los caracteres de una y de otra. Y si hay menos de 3 diferencias que te los muestre y decides ya lo que hacer. Pero piensa que Valencia y Palencia son ciudades diferentes.

Comment: Puedes revisar estas preguntas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings#17388505

Comment: y también https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690739/high-performance-fuzzy-string-comparison-in-python-use-levenshtein-or-difflib

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que "A Coruna" y "A Coruña" cuentan como el mismo, pero en cambio "Palencia" y "Valencia" no, me temo que ninguna solución automática servirá. Sí que puedes usar un agregador basado en fuzzywuzzy o difflib para encontrar automáticamente las agrupaciones de palabras parecidas, pero después de eso yo volcaría esos resultados a unos "diccionarios de traducción" que después revisaría a mano para eliminar falsos positivos como "Valencia/Palencia". Con ese diccionario ya curado por mi, lo usaría para la comparación o conversión a forma canónica.

Comment: Mírate [thefuzz](https://pypi.org/project/thefuzz/). En lugar de ir comprobando una a una, puedes chequear una lista completa y elegir las opciones que más se han aproximado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La librería `difflib` de Python contiene una variedad de métodos para trabajar con textos y encontrar similitudes/diferencias.

El método `difflib.SequenceMatcher`

> es una clase flexible para comparar pares de secuencias de
> cualquier tipo, siempre que los elementos de la secuencia sean
> hashable. El algoritmo básico es anterior, y un poco mas agradable,
> que el publicado a fines de los 80” por Ratcliff y Obershelp, bajo el
> nombre hiperbólico de «gestalt pattern matching». La idea es encontrar
> la subsecuencia coincidente contigua mas larga que no contenga
> elementos «no deseados»; estos elementos «no deseados» son aquellos
> que no son de interés por algún motivo, como ser lineas en blanco o
> espacios. (El tratamiento de elementos no deseados es una extensión al
> algoritmo de Ratcliff y Obershelp). La misma idea se aplica
> recursivamente a las partes de la secuencia a la derecha e izquierda
> de cada subsecuencia correspondiente. Esto no proporciona secuencias
> de edición mínimas, pero tiende a producir coincidencias que «parecen
> correctas» a las personas.

Una aplicación básica es comparar dos palabras para obtener un indicador de similitud. Este es un valor entre 0 y 1, donde 1 representa coincidencia absoluto y 0 dice que no hay nada en común entre ambos textos. Sólo queda elegir el valor de corte sobre el cual se aceptara la equivalencia. Lo usual es aceptar la similitud cuando el índice es >= 0.6.

Entonces una solución es comparar cada ciudad contra una lista oficial de ciudades y elegir la que más se parezca, chequeando todas las posibilidades

Hice esta pequeña demo donde `oficiales` es la lista oficial de ciudades y `ciudades` es la lista a validar.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

oficiales = ["Melipilla", "Melilla", "Maripul"]
ciudades = ["Melilla", "Melipiya", "Meliya", "Meli-pilla"]

for ciudad in ciudades:
    print(f"Ciudad: {ciudad}")
    ciudad_encontrada = None
    parecido = 0
    for oficial in oficiales:
        ptos = similar(ciudad, oficial)
        if ptos > parecido:
            parecido = ptos
            ciudad_encontrada = oficial

    print(f"Ciudad {ciudad} es {ciudad_encontrada} con similitud {parecido}")
```

produce:

```
Ciudad: Melilla
Ciudad Melilla es Melilla con similitud 1.0
Ciudad: Melipiya
Ciudad Melipiya es Melipilla con similitud 0.8235294117647058
Ciudad: Meliya
Ciudad Meliya es Melilla con similitud 0.7692307692307693
Ciudad: Meli-pilla
Ciudad Meli-pilla es Melipilla con similitud 0.9473684210526315

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

me he visto con algo similar hace poco, mi solución ha sido crear una segunda tabla con alias

en mi caso las distintas formas de recibir cada provincia era limitada,tengo una tabla con las provincias con el nombre que a mi me interesa y otra con cada nombre que puedo esperar de cada provincia y el nombre que yo espero.

todos los alias los tengo pasados a minusculas y sin caracteres especiales y así realizo la busqueda sobre el alias y me quedo con mi nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta no es una solución, pues implica que el OP debe manualmente construir la tabla de sinónimos.

Comment: "en mi caso las distintas formas de recibir cada provincia era limitada" sabemos si este es su caso?

Comment: Ofreces una solución manual en un sitio de preguntas/respuestas sobre programación. Con un comentario habría bastado.

Comment: ofrezco la solución que encontré a un problema en el que me he visto yo también. esos 4 casos que comenta arriba se convierten en 1 eliminando mayusculas espacios y caracteres especiales al nombre de entrada.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta. En mi caso no es limitado, puede haber muchos registros de ese estilo con fallos y que al final sean la misma ciudad

Comment: además va a ser imposible no tener una tabla de sinónimos cuando puedes encontrar castellano catalan euskera y gallego en los nombres de provincias

Comment: yo lo que hice fue eso, pillas el nombre, le quitas las mayusculas le quitas los espacios y los caracteres especiales y 

A Coruña
A Coruna
Acoruna
Acoruña

se convierten en "acoruna"

esa sabla de A coruña-acoruna la generas automáticamente y cuando busco, modifico el nombre de entrada igual que hice al generar los alias, y siempre habrán unos cuantos casos que tendrás que tratar a mano, yo no me vi otra mejor para tratar los nombres en idiomas regionales

Comment: y estoy pensando que una vez tienes los alias ya es mas facil ponerse a contar letras y bloques de texto coincidentes y tratar de obtener algún tipo de puntuacion para elegir la mejor coincidencia

Comment: sigo pensando que creo que ya se como hacerlo...

una vez tuviese los alias obtendría un ratio de letras coincidentes-letras en la privincia original

cuanto mas coincidencias haya y menos diferencia de letras haya entre ellas más puntuación

luego compararía bloques de 2,3 y 4 letras, y lo mismo, cuantas más coincidencias haya en esos bloques, de nuevo, mas puntuación a esas provincias.

creo que sería bastante efectivo

Answer (score 0):

Existe una librería llamada "FuzzyWuzzy" y funciona de la siguiente manera:

Le mandas 2 String y te retorna un % de parecido ejemplo:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

E imprime 97